# unable to install any module with pip without doing sudo

Tags: python, pip

I am not able to install any module with pip unless I do it with sudo. Below is error trace.

```
LAP:models$ pip install -U scikit-learn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==8.0.3
```

I looked online but did not find any solution so far.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @k-nut : I want to install virtualenv also but without sudo